# How to use where condition for laravel eloquent with function ( into the child table)

Tags: laravel-5.5

**My Post Model like**:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class **Post** extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
    }
}
```

And **User** Model like:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function userType(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_type_id','id');
    }
}
```

Now if I call the following in my controller:

**$posts = \App\Post::with('user.userType')->where('status', 1)->get();**

It returns all the posts for posts.status = 1, with users table data and also user_type.

**What should I do??**, if I want to set a where condition for users table or for user_types table like: where('user.id', 5) or where('user_types.id', 1).

Is it possible?? if yes please answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should improve your questions... I don't understand what you need.

Comment: I tried to reword your question to make it more clear, please review my changes and adapt as necessary.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for your suggestion